# From the HTML, is there any way to know which web page directed me to a specific webpage (after redirection)?

Tags: html

If I'm already scraping the code of a webpage, is there any way to know from its HTML which websites redirect to that page?

Comment: You want to know what random pages link to that page?? That would be impossible from that page. I am sure whatever you are using to scrape has an option to not follow redirects?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, basically I need information on how a user can potentially land up at that page.

Comment: There is no way to know what links to that page without being on a page that links to it.

Comment: You could do this via PHP, using [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). With JS, you'd use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer). Both of those only work if it is your page. When you're scraping, you're out of luck.

Comment: @epascarello No, I am scraping through the HTML to search for any metadata that could tell me what pages redirect or link to that page on which I am. Which you said is impossible.

Comment: In HTML., there is no data that tells you what links to it. I can link to that page here. I can do it on twitter, I can do it on facebook. There is no way to know those links exist form that page. That is why there are crawlers that build up a map of a site and can tell you want links to it.

Comment: @epascarello That makes sense. What about automaric redirects?

Comment: Usually no. Some pages set cookies when redirected by a parameter in the url e.g. `http://www.example.org/?affiliate=foo`, then those usually get shortened which also encrypts them slightly.

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

The HTML source of a website does not contain such information. Anyone is free to link/redirect to any other page, and the act of doing so can not possibly modify the HTML of the page that is being linked to.